# Why is my php forget password not sending out the email

Tags: php, email

The query wise is working fine, i can echo out the email address and the password associated to the username however when it states that the email is being sent out i still do not receive it in my mailbox. Any idea what went wrong?

Here's my full code:

```
<?php session_start();
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");//database connection
mysql_select_db("database");
if (isset($_POST['username'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $query="select * from dbusers where username='$username'";
    $result   = mysql_query($query);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    // If the count is equal to one, we will send message other wise display an error message.
    if($count==1)
    {
        $rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $pass  =  $rows['password'];//FETCHING PASS
        echo "your pass is ::".($pass)."";
        $to = $rows['email'];
        echo "your email is ::".$to;
        //Details for sending E-mail
        $from = "Your Password details";
        $url = "http://localhost.com";
        $body  =  "Reset Password
        -----------------------------------------------
        Url : $url;
        email Details is : $to;
        Here is your password  : $pass;
        Sincerely,
        Coding Cyber";
        $from = "admin@support.com";
        $subject = "Here's your new password";
        $headers1 = "From: $from\n";
        $sentmail = mail ( $to, $subject, $body, $headers1 );
    } else {
    if ($_POST ['username'] != "") {
    echo "No such username found!</span>";
        }
        }
    //If the message is sent successfully, display sucess message otherwise display an error message.
    if($sentmail==1)
    {
        echo "<span style='color: #ff0000;'> Your Password Has Been Sent To Your Email Address.</span>";
    }
        else
        {
        if($_POST['username']!="")
        echo "<span style='color: #ff0000;'> Cannot send password to your e-mail address.Problem with sending mail...</span>";
    }
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Home: Webpage</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
        <label> Enter your User ID : </label>
        <input id="username" type="text" name="username" />
        <input id="button" type="submit" name="button" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The fact it doesn't work is PHP's way of telling you you should never ever ever store plain text passwords.

Comment: Do you have mail server?

Comment: @christian I only have xampp running with phpmyadmin and apache up.

Comment: If you have XAMPP installed, then just start the Mercury Mail Transport

Comment: Enabled it already, still aint working. @MarcelBalzer

Comment: Please never use this code. Password plain text has been mentioned but beside this it is very vulnerable to sql injection attacks (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Again: Never use this code.

Answer (score 1):

When you use xampp: Activate your Mercury Mail Transport in your xampp-control.
Otherwise, your local mailserver is not started and you cant send Mails.

```
<?php
$a = 'your@email.com';
$b = ''; 
$msg = 'Hello';
$header = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($a, $b, $msg, $header);
?>
```

Comment: I've activated mecury mail transport, tried to rerun the code but still email not getting into mailbox. Any solutions?

Comment: Try to make a new PHP - Page, with only mail(xyz) to eliminate other errors in your code, and write if it worked or not :)
check your spam folder aswell

Comment: Sorry what do u mean by that new php page? could u enlighten me with typing some codes out?

Comment: check my editing: open a new project and a new page, and type that in ( with your mail adress ) and check, if you get an email :)

Comment: Hmmm, ive just tried and enabled mercury mail transport. still unable to receive the email. does it work on your side?

Comment: At the moment - I am at work, cant try - I will try it when I am at home at 18:00

Comment: Hello, sorry I am just writing now, you should try to upload it, on funpic for example to check the mail function - its working for me with my local webserver settings. Its probably cause its localhost. Upload it on funpic or another free webhoster, and check if ur email will arrive!

Answer (score 0):

If your files are in your localhost folder you need to install a local mail server, not pretty usefull, but it works.

And if yout website in online ( at a hoster ) it should works automatically, or go to the cpanel and activate the mailing.

Comment: Hi how do u go upon installing this mail server in my htdocs folder? (localhost)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your code in your localhost then that will never work for you.It's better if you want to send mail from your local server then use SMTP rather than simple mail functionality by PHP.